# I don't understand the result of this JavaScript example :console.log(array1.copyWithin(1, 3));

Tags: javascript

```js
  const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
    
    // copy to index 0 the element at index 3
    console.log(array1.copyWithin(0, 3, 4));
    // expected output: Array ["d", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
    
    // copy to index 1 all elements from index 3 to the end
    console.log(array1.copyWithin(1, 3));
    // expected output: Array ["d", "d", "e", "d", "e"]
```

so why the result of the second console.log is  ["d", "d", "e", "d", "e"] , I expected that will be :
['a', 'd', 'e', 'd', 'e'] , help me to understand this example from MDN

Comment: oh I understand why the rustle is like above , because array1.copyWithin change the array .

Answer (score 2):

`copyWithin` changes the actual array in place, 
So after the first line: `array1.copyWithin(0, 3, 4)`, 
array1 will be `["d", "b", "c", "d", "e"]`. 
Then after `array1.copyWithin(1, 3)` the result is `["d", "d", "e", "d", "e"]`

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/copyWithin), `copyWithin` modifies the array you call it upon. After your first call of `copyWithin`, there is no element `a` in that array anymore